# why we need to migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, upgrade

We have a Web API project on ASP.NET Core 2.1 working perfectly fine. I would like to know what are the benefits to migrating to latest ASP.NET Core 3.1? (We also have news of the release of ASP.NET Core 5.0.)

If someone can help me out with valid points, whether it is really recommended to upgrade to the latest LTS supportive framework, ASP.NET Core 3.1, so I can take action to upgrade.

Comment: Faster, new libs are going to support it, easier to move to .net 5. Practically speaking you should strive to keep up otherwise your code will quickly become obsolete

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Are you the one who pays the bills, salaries and pizzas to all the developers who have to carry out the porting and the tests? Are you the one who collects payments from customers who are enthusiastic about this evolution of your software? If you ask me, I would say yes, but developing software is only one aspect of it.

Comment: Go and look into release notes for every single version of ASP and you will find an answer to your question

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 LTS will go out of support on 30th August 2021 (see https://endoflife.date/dotnetcore), so you've got 14 months to update to 3.1. After that, you won't receive any security patches for 2.1. It would be better for you to move sooner rather than later, otherwise if you leave it to the last minute and have unexpected issues, you might go past the EoL date.

Comment: Security standards probably is the most convincing argument here for a corporation. 3.1 had closed some vulnerabilities in the framework that were discovered and leaving it at 2.1 is a problem if you have sensitive information.

Comment: @misha130 - can you please give a link for your comments?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1.1/3.1.1.md#changes-in-311
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1.4/3.1.4.md#changes-in-314

Hold on never mind, I looked into it more and these patches were also applied to 2.1 via 2.1.8 etc

Comment: so it is in asp.net 3.1.1 & 3.1.4 --> not in 3.1.0  ( which is LTS version? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if it is not very complicated for you, you should keep your project on the newest version.

The advantages are, for example, fixing some issues in the older version, and easier migration to .NET 5 in the future (which is also something you should focus on if you can).

Comment: Note that .NET 5 will not be an LTS version, but .NET 6 will.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you will find this article by *Travis J. Gosselin* useful and descriptive on the reasons to/not to migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 [Why Upgrade Your .NET Core API from 2.x to 3.1?](http://blog.travisgosselin.com/why-upgrade-your-net-core-api-from-2-x-to-3-1/)

If you want to proceed with the migration, then you may find *maherjendoubi*'s reply to [Migrate Asp.Net Core 2.1 to 3.1](https://forums.asp.net/t/2162862.aspx?Migrate%20Asp%20Net%20Core%202%201%20to%203%201) topic on asp forms useful.

The proper way to carry out the procedure can be found in Microsoft documentation, it is quite descriptive in itself. Do refer [2.0 to 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-3.1), [2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), [2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and [3.0 to 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to get the exact details.